# Are there technical downsides to using a single collection over multiple collections in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Since MongoDB is schemaless, I could just drop all my documents into a single collection, with a key `collection` and an index on that key.

For example this:

```js
db.getCollection('dogs').find()
db.getCollection('cars').find()
```

Would become this:

```js
db.getCollection('all').find({'collection': 'dogs'})
db.getCollection('all').find({'collection': 'cars'})
```

Is there any technical downside to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons to have different collections, maybe the two most importants are:

- Performance: even if MongoDB has been designed to be flexible, it doesn't prevent the need to have indexes on fields that will be used during the search. You would have dramatic response times if the collection is too heterogeneous.
- Maintenability/evolutivity: design should be driven by the usecases (usually you'll store the data as it's received by the application) and the design should be explicit to anyone looking at the database collections

MongoDB University is a great e-learning platform, it is free and there is in particular this course:

- [M320: Data Modeling](https://university.mongodb.com/courses/M320/about)

Answer (score 0):

schema questions are often better understood by working backwards from the queries you'll rely on and how the data will get written....   if you were going to query Field1 AND Field2 together in 1 query statement you do want them in the same collection....dogs and cars don't sound very related while dogs and cats do...so really look at how you're going to want to query.....joining collections is not really ideal - doable via $lookup but not ideal....